# To remove the Add to Cart button from a specific product and replace a link instead

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I searched about removing the Add to Cart button from a specific product and I used this code in functions.php.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'my_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2);
function my_woocommerce_is_purchasable($is_purchasable, $product) {
        return ($product->id == 305 ? false : $is_purchasable);
}
```

Now I want to replace a direct download link instead of the Add to Cart button.
I have free products and I want direct download link instead of the Add to Cart button.

EDITED:
I used this code but I saw direct download link in all single-product page. I want to see direct download link just in pages which have free product.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_startsinfo', 11 );
function woocommerce_template_single_startsinfo() { 
echo '<div class="starsinfo">
<p><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Test.apk">direct download</a>
</div>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The add to cart button is really an HTML a element. You can change the href of this HTML a element by using the filter 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url'.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', function( $url, $product ) {
    return $your_url;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Of course, you should use the $product which is a subclass of WC_Product to determine $your_url.

Comment: Please give an example